# MongoDB - $addToSet for an Array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb, aggregation-framework

Structure:

```
[
 {
  "_id": "12",
  "title": "Vanella Icream",
  "contain":"sugar",
  "details": [
      {
        "flavour": "Vanella"
      },
      {
        "weight": "6KG"
      }
   ]
 },
 {
  "_id": "3",
  "title": "Pretzels",
  "contain":"salt",
  "details": [
      {
        "flavour": "Wheat"
      },
      {
        "weight": "2KG"
      }
   ]
 }
]
```

**Expected Output**

```
details:
{
      "flavour": [
        "Vanella",
        "Wheat",
      ],
      "weight": [
        "6KG",
        "2KG",
      ]
}
```

**More Important**: I've to do this **without** `details.flavour` or `details.weight`.

I’ve tried with **$addToSet**, **$filter** **$group** but I’m not getting results like that. anyone please suggest.

Mongo Playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/SXw3jaRDzLy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$project` to show required field
- `$unwind` deconstruct the `details` array
- `$objectToArray` convert `details` object to array key-value format
- `$unwind` deconstruct the `details` array
- `$group` by details key and construct the array of values
- `$group` by null and construct the array of `details` in key-value format
- `$arrayToObject` convert above result from key-value format array of object to an object

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      details: 1
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$details" },
  {
    $project: {
      details: { $objectToArray: "$details" }
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$details" },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$details.k",
      v: { $addToSet: "$details.v" }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      details: {
        $push: { k: "$_id", v: "$v" }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      details: { $arrayToObject: "$details" }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/q5tsdWdJCCp)